# Can I use Sketchapp to design entire website

Tags: web, sketchapp

I am a freelancer who wants to start using Sketchapp to make more trendy websites (slanted and curved line backgrounds, UI assets that have shadows, assets that go over 2 divs (see examples). Can and do freelancers (do both their own design and code) use Sketchapp to create the entire site for everything (**including text**) as their normal best practice and to speed up workflow and then just export everything to text editor and then tweak? Below are 2 examples that I aspire to be able to create.

[Example 1 from Pinterest](http://res.cloudinary.com/dakhz1yax/image/upload/v1511023974/c20b747e66dbd60377b779a09612a04d_auv5n0.jpg)

[Example 2 from Pinterest](http://res.cloudinary.com/dakhz1yax/image/upload/v1511023976/5490b651094049.58e29fd3462f9_xdmhxc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes and No. The first example is highly using textures and graphics which is hard to do in Sketch. But for that you need to use Photoshop. For the second example is more flat and not using much graphical effect. its minimal and flat. Sketch is really fasten up your working flow to create something like that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely could create both designs in sketch but it won't be the only program you have to use to finish this job. At least if you produce each used graphic yourself.

In the first design for example you have quite a lot gradients an brush technics between the sections. Here you would need to use brushes in Photoshop to achive this look. After this you could export the layers as PNGs with transparent background and import those into sketch...

Sketch is perfect to use with SVG. I would say wen you work with SVGs you can almost only use sketch.

Hope this answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

> to speed up workflow and then just export everything to text editor and then tweak

First you create the website design in Sketch and then you start writing the HTML/CSS code by hand. This is how the web development process goes.

You could also use helper tools like Desech Studio to import the Sketch file and then adjust the html/css faster.

Unfortunately it's not possible to create a website in the design stack like Sketch, and also work in the web stack. These 2 stacks are different in how they work.

Alternatively you could start designing the website directly in HTML/CSS and skip the design stack completely, but you will be slower and it will be harder to make changes, compared to the design stack.